# How to remove css selector with notepad + + regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi looking to remove all the selectors UNUSED in notepad ++ regular expressions:

```
    UNUSED#colorbox,UNUSED#cboxOverlay,UNUSED#cboxWrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    }

    UNUSED.jcarousel-list li,UNUSED.jcarousel-item {
    list-style:none;
    }

    UNUSEDdt,UNUSEDdd,UNUSEDol,form,label,UNUSEDlegend,UNUSEDtable,UNUSEDcaption,UNUSEDtbody,UNUSEDtfoot,UNUSEDthead,UNUSEDtr,UNUSEDth,UNUSEDtd,UNUSEDhr,input,UNUSEDbutton {
border:0;
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

}

**look it is thus not how to get it:**

```
li {
list-style:none;
}

form,label,input {
border:0;
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Which version of Notepad++ is used?

Comment: hi, Notedpad++ v6.3.3

Comment: are you still interested in the solution?